# Inconsistencies when removing elements from a Bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

When using bash arrays, you can remove an element in the following manner:

```
unset array[i]   # where i is the array index
```

The problem with this is after the unset ${array[@]] is not truly valid. Yes
it does give you the number of active array elements, but not the actual array
depth. The index of the removed index in the array still exists. It simply has
been set inactive/null. For example:

```
declare -a array=( a b c d e )
unset array[2]

for ((i=0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++)) ; do
    echo "$i: ${array[$i]}"
done
```

outputs the following:

```
0: a
1: b
2:
3: d
```

array[2] is still there but set to null or inactive

array[4] (e) does not show because ${#array[@]} is the number of active
array elements and not the true array element depth. This gets very messy very
quickly each time an element is unset

As an example consider the following code:

# array contains 0 or more strings
# remove looks for and removes a given string

```
remove () {

    local str=$1

    for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#array[@]}; i++ )) ; do
        if [[ "${array[$i]}" == "$str" ]] ; then
            unset array[$i]
            return 0
        fi
    done

    echo "$str: not registered"

    return 0
}
```

This is only valid the first time remove is called. After that, valid
elements may be missed.

One fix for this is to added the following line after the unset:

```
     unset array[$i]
  +  array=( "${array[@]}" )
```

This re-initializes array with the element completely removed.

The problem, this feels kludgy.

So my questions are this:

1)  is there a way of getting the true array element depth?

2)  is there a way of detecting the end of an array when iterating through it?

3)  is there another cleaner solution?

Comment: This port will provide insights:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74197/how-to-unset-range-of-array-in-bash

Comment: BTW, I suspect you'd be better off using associative arrays here, with the strings you potentially want to remove things by used as indices. That makes the removal a very fast O(1) operation. Sometimes, it's not even necessary to have values at all -- I've been known to write code with associative arrays where every value is `1`, and all the important data is in the keys.

Comment: I thought about using associative array. But it annoyed me that I couldn't get my head around this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Understanding *Why* `for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++))` is broken

There's no such thing as "true array element depth" in the sense that you're asking for here. Bash arrays aren't really arrays -- they're hash maps (numerically indexed for regular arrays, indexed by strings for bash 4.0's new "associative arrays"). As such, there's absolutely no reason for the keys to start from 0 -- you can have an array like the following: `declare -a array=( [1000]="one thousand" [2000]="two thousand" [3000]="three thousand" )`, and its length is exactly 3; there aren't a bunch of NUL/empty elements sitting between those items (looked up with keys `1000`, `2000` and `3000`, respectively).

---

#### Removing Elements From A Sparse Array Safely

Iterate over indices, if you want to remove by index. Whereas `"${array[@]}"` iterates over items in the array, `"${!array[@]}"` (note the `!`) iterates over by the indices by which those items can be looked up.

As you've observed, it's unsafe to assume that the indices range from 0 to the total number of items in an array, as bash arrays are allowed to be sparse -- but there's no reason to write your code to make that assumption in the first place.

```
for array_idx in "${!array[@]}"; do
  unset "array[$array_idx]"
done
```

Comment: @Craig I am happy that this post answered your question, please consider accepting it. Take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).